# Change variables of a Jacobian

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

If I have a change of variable, made by a diffeomorphism, the determinant of the Jacobian preserves the sign?(if it is positive it remains positive)

Comment: I think you need to be a little more explicit. What kind of variable change? The Jacobian of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a diffeomorphism is orientation-preserving if and only if the determinant of its Jacobian matrix is positive. On a connected domain, the sign of the determinant cannot change.

Comment: Let f a smooth function between manifolds. I have x1,...,xn y1,...,yn coordinates and a diffeomorphism between these. If i know that $det(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j})_p$ is positive can I conclude that $det(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j})_p$ is positive too?

Comment: No. The transformation $\phi(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (y_1,\dots,y_n)$ may be orientation-reversing.

Comment: And if I know that the diffeo preserves the orientation?

Comment: Now I guess I'm confused. You're thinking of $x$ and $y$ as two different coordinate systems on manifold $M$, and you have $f\colon M\to N$. You fix a coordinate system $z_1,\dots,z_n$ on $N$ and when you write $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$ you mean $\frac{\partial(z_i\circ f)}{\partial x_j}$. At any rate, the chain rule tells how to differentiate $f\circ x^{-1} = (f\circ y^{-1})\circ \phi$. That is, you have $\left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\right] = \left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}\right]D\phi$.

Comment: I have not explain well the question. As you say I have a function between M,N oriented manifold. I know that the function preserves the orientation if $\frac {\partial f_i}{\partial x_i}$ preserve the orientation. Suppose f preserve the orientation. Now, if I pick another coordinate system in M, $y_1,..,y_n$ I can claim that the $\frac {\partial f_i}{\partial y_i}$ preserve the orientation too? Thanks for the attention and sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: sorry I've understood! thanks

Comment: It takes a while to get used to this stuff :) If you're happy with this, please accept the answer so that this question will not stay on the unanswered list.

Comment: @TedShifrin I do not know how to leave a massege so i comment here. I gave an answer to this [Q](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659413/what-does-this-notation-mean-derivative-of-a-1-form/659473#659473) I want to if it is correct or no? what is the right one? Thanks in advance